NestJS application in a monorepo with Yarn Workspaces imports only types, not functions from its packages
I am working with Yarn Workspaces in a monorepo with the following structure:
├───monorepo
│   ├───node_modules
│   ├───apps
│   │   ├───backend
│   │   │   ├───node_modules
│   │   │   └───src
│   │   └───frontend
│   │       ├───.next
│   │       ├───node_modules
│   │       ├───app
│   │       └───public
│   └───packages
│       ├───util
│       │   ├───node_modules
│       │   └───src
│       └───types
│           ├───node_modules
│           └───src

The "util" and "types" packages have exactly the same package.json and tsconfig.json configurations but serve different purposes.
While "types" provides typings for the applications, "util" provides functions for formatting, conversion, calculations, etc.
Here are the package configurations:
/packages/(util | types)/package.json
{
  "name": "@monorepo/util",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {}
}

/packages/(util | types)/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}

Here are the files in "util"
/packages/util/index.ts
export * from "./date-formatting";

/packages/util/src/date-formatting.ts
export const formatShortDate = (date: Date) => {
    return date.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { day: "numeric", month: "numeric" });
};

The frontend can correctly consume both packages with their typings and functions, but the backend can only consume the typings. When I import a function from "util", TypeScript recognizes the path correctly, but when I run the application, the following error is triggered:
export * from "./date-formatting";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)

The packages are properly installed in the applications:
/apps/(frontend | backend)/package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@monorepo/util": "*",
    "@monorepo/types": "*",
    ...
}

Here are the TypeScript configuration files for the applications:
/apps/(backend)/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}

/apps/(frontend)/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

What could I be doing wrong? Thank you in advance for answers.
Here is the repo url: https://github.com/anthonyvictor/monorepo/
I have already tried reinstalling all packages, started the monorepo from scratch, tested all "targets" in the tsconfig.json of the packages, but without success. Any solution?
